# STM32CubeIDE Project

Tags: stm32

I have tried to open existing stm32 project on different computer (computer is not connected to internet). When I try to open the project file, there is a html file which is showed on screen. What is the problem? Does internet connection cause this error?

Comment: You almost certainly need an internet connection the 1st time you open an existing project on a PC with a fresh installation of STM32CubeMX. The application needs to download various packages for the specific STM32 microcontroller and whatever 'middleware' you might have included in the project, as many of these are not installed when you first install the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot...